# error when installing xdebug with phpize

Tags: php, xdebug

I am trying to install xdebug, so I used the custom installation options on the site, when it came to "phpize" I get the error:

Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

even if I use the full path to phpize I get the same error.

I am using OS X Lion

Thanks

Ric

Answer (score 3):

I was getting that error as well. What you should do is run it in the xdebug 2.2.1 directory inside the xdebug 2.2.1 directory. The second directory has a lot of files which makes sense to run the command when you've changed to that directory. This took me past that step.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue is fixed here: http://kmaiti.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/cannot-find-configm4-phpize-resolved.html
And there is a similar PHP Bug page here too: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58650

There seems to be an issue with the location the command is run, try running it in the actual source directory for xdebug.